# JPanel in different class, is what I did bad ? why?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, jpanel

I made a new class that extended JFrame and new class that extended JPanel to make the swing GUI. It is great, I like this due to its ease of readability.

However, when it comes to event handling things started getting complex. What I did really doesn't really seem like a solution; just like breaking good habit to make something work. How do I make this work properly?

This is my JFrame class

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public MainFrame(String title){
        super(title);

        //set layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //create components
        JButton buttonOne = new JButton("click me");
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        JPanel detailedPanel = new leftPanel();

        //add to panel
        Container c = getContentPane();

        c.add(buttonOne, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        c.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(detailedPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        //Event Listening
        leftPanel.buttonAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + " " + leftPanel.fieldName.getText() + " : " + leftPanel.fieldOccupation.getText());
            }

        });

    }

}
```

this is my JPanel

```
public class leftPanel extends JPanel {

    public static JTextField fieldName;
    public static JTextField fieldOccupation;
    public static JButton buttonAdd;

    public leftPanel(){
        Dimension panelSize = getPreferredSize();
        panelSize.width = 250;
        setPreferredSize(panelSize);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Personal Info"));

        //labels
        JLabel labelName = new JLabel("name: ");
        JLabel labelOccupation = new JLabel("Occupation: ");

        //textFields
        fieldName = new JTextField(10);
        fieldOccupation = new JTextField(10);

        //buttons
        buttonAdd = new JButton("Add !");

        //actions
        buttonAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //on click
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String name = fieldName.getText();
                String occupation = fieldOccupation.getText();

                System.out.print(name + ": " + occupation);                    
            }    
        });

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //// First Y  add //////////////////////////////////////

        //label NAME
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(labelName, gbc);

        //label Occupation
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(labelOccupation, gbc);

        //// SECOND Y add /////////////////////////////////////  

        //text field name
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.weightx = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(fieldName, gbc);

        //text feld occupation
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.weightx = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(fieldOccupation, gbc);

        //// THIRD Y add //////////////////////////////////////

        //add button
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 10;
        add(buttonAdd, gbc); 
    }
}
```

Comment: offtopic... Is a good practice to name your classes with the first letter in Upper case... `public class leftPanel` could be `public class LeftPanel`

Comment: Also, `static` is not your friend here, it is NOT a cross object communication mechanism and should never be used in this way

Answer (score 5):

For the most part, you component should be as self contained as possible, this would suggest that the component should be responsible for handling the events generated by it's immediate children.

This doesn't mean that the component won't then generate it's own events, but that the component manages it's immediate children itself.

You should try and avoid exposing your child components directly (using `public` fields or `getters`) or indirectly (through event objects), this invites possible misuse of those components by external sources, which is never going to be pleasant.

In your example, your first class only wants to known when something happens that would require it to update the text area.

This would suggest that the `LeftPanel` needs to generate some kind of event (maybe a `ActionEvent`) and provide a `getter` for anybody who might be interested to gain access to the information that the `LeftPanel` is managing.

For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LeftPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField fieldName;
    private JTextField fieldOccupation;
    private JButton buttonAdd;

    public LeftPanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Personal Info"));

        //labels
        JLabel labelName = new JLabel("name: ");
        JLabel labelOccupation = new JLabel("Occupation: ");

        //textFields
        fieldName = new JTextField(10);
        fieldOccupation = new JTextField(10);

        //buttons
        buttonAdd = new JButton("Add !");

        //actions
        buttonAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            //on click
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireActionPerformed();
            }
        });

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //// First Y  add //////////////////////////////////////
        //label NAME
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(labelName, gbc);

        //label Occupation
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(labelOccupation, gbc);

        //// SECOND Y add /////////////////////////////////////  
        //text field name
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.weightx = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(fieldName, gbc);

        //text feld occupation
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.weightx = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(fieldOccupation, gbc);

        //// THIRD Y add //////////////////////////////////////
        //add button
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 10;
        add(buttonAdd, gbc);

    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    protected void fireActionPerformed() {
        ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        if (listeners.length > 0) {
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "PropertiesSet");
            for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPersonName() {
        return fieldName.getText();
    }

    public String getPersonOccupation() {
        return fieldOccupation.getText();
    }

}
```

The `LeftPanel` here now manages the internal state of it's components (no `static` or `public` fields).  It also provides a `ActionListener` support to provide notification to interested parties who can obtain the information the component is managing via getters

The `MainFrame` then simply uses an instance of `LeftPanel` and registers a `ActionListener` to it so it can be notified when the panel has been updated and uses the getters to obtain the information it's interested in.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        //set layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //create components
        JButton buttonOne = new JButton("click me");
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        LeftPanel detailedPanel = new LeftPanel();

        //add to panel
        Container c = getContentPane();

        c.add(buttonOne, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        c.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(detailedPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        //Event Listening
        detailedPanel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.append(textArea.getText() + " " + detailedPanel.getPersonName() + " : " + detailedPanel.getPersonOccupation() + "\n");
            }

        });

    }

}
```

In OO, you want to encapsulate the logic and responsibility to the object and then, as required, from callbacks (such as a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)) to provide notification to interested parties that some predefined state has changed.  Then simply expose the information that the object is managing via getters (and where required, setters for others to change the information as required)